# Is there an all inclusive C++ game engine that is free

Tags: c++

I would like to know if there is a C++ game engine that I can use for free to prototype some ideas I have.

I have experience in C++ and have spent some time now playing around with different rendering engines such as Ogre3d and irrlicht. I don't want to re-invent the wheel and spend the time building my own engine.

I have some ideas for a game that I would like to prototype and would be looking for a free engine to experiment with. I would be open to paying for the engine if I can make my idea work but as I don't have a great deal of time or resources I would need the engine to not have a time limit on free use.

By all inclusive I mean: I would rather not have to get a whole bunch of separate dependencies for physics, sound etc. I would prefer the one engine to have those things in it.

It might be a big ask as well but some of my ideas are of a more advanced nature so ideally not free because it limits the features for free use. I want something I can use to prototype some ideas and would be happy to pay for if the project went past the prototype stage.

Comment: I'd argue that "C++" and "prototyping" don't really go all that well together.  Depending [on your goals](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13/when-creating-quick-prototypes-is-it-better-to-use-the-language-you-are-going-to) of course.

Answer (score 3):

[Comparison of free AAA game engines](http://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/jmwf0/comparison_of_free_aaa_game_engines_cryengine/).

Those are going to be your best options. You haven't really given enough information for me to suggest past that, but the breakdown should be detailed enough for you to choose.

Comment: Thanks man. I appreciate the link. I'm sure I can find something there.

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to just create a prototype for your games you can use [Esenthel Engine](http://www.esenthel.com). it's basically designed for an mmorpg games, but it has reach framework for any kind of game you need to create. ofcourse you can expand your prototypes to full game using this engine but i'm not sure how the results will be.

Answer (score -1):

Prototyping only ? I personally think using C++ to prototype in 2014 is just for someone who's not serious about his ideas and is just working for a school project or something.

If you have a game idea and you're thinking of making your first steps (prototype) then going with [Unity3D](http://www.unity3d.com) is a good start it allows you to code your game details in JavaScript which is WAY simpler and it takes care of the C++ (hardware) part which includes memory management, rendering and texturing and executing your actual JavaScript game level instructions.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, but a personal opinion. Please use the comment feature in the future.

Comment: @PhilipAllgaier  wish I could have been able to comment, unfortunately, the system told me that I must have at least 50 reputation to comment, which I don't because I'm new. I wish you could upvote my answer instead to help me raise my reputation.